# Execute PHPSpreadsheet via batch script / task scheduler

Tags: php, batch-file, phpspreadsheet

I have created two php files, the perform two separate tasks.

  1. The first script uses PHPSpreadsheet to create an populated my report template which is an xlsx file.  This works perfectly when run directly through the browser (Google Chrome).

  2. The second script uses PHPMailer to then pickup this file and attach it to an e-mail.  Again this works perfectly when executed through the browser.

I have tried running the same scripts using a batch file, but this is where the first section fails.  The Xlsx file never gets created, and hence an e-mail gets sent without attaching the document.

I have tried running each script individually via the batch script.

The second part (sending the mail) works as expected.

Creating the file via the batch script seems to be the issue.

```
REM This adds the folder containing php.exe to the path
PATH=%PATH%;C:\php


REM Change Directory to the folder containing your script
CD C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpspreadsheet\reporting

REM Execute
php report_v1.1.php


REM Change Directory to the folder containing your script
CD C:\Apache24\htdocs\Automation

REM Execute
php report.php
```

I would like to automate these two scripts to run sequentially, so that I can automate sending out the report to the relevant recipients.  I do not get any error message from the first script, only a lot of random characters on the terminal screen when executing it via command line to test.

[image]

Comment: What error do you get when the first script dies?

Comment: No error message is produced.  The is a lot of random text that dis displayed in the terminal screen when I run it in terminal.

Comment: Even with error reporting enabled?

Comment: I have added an image of what is outputted on terminal

Comment: That looks like PHP is dumping the spreadsheet's contents to the output. Any chance you're writing the end result of the spreadsheet to `php://output`?

Comment: AS first script is Browser Based, you will have to take all the HTMl etc out of that script. Did you do that?

Comment: I do have php://output at the end of first script, should I remove this? ```$writer->save('php://output');```

Also, I don't have any html in the first script.

Comment: There are two options I can think of.
One: replace that part of the script with something like this: `$writer->save(php_sapi_name() === 'cli' ? 'somefile.xlsx' : 'php://output');`.
Two: redirect the script's output to a file like this: `php report_v1.1.php > somefile.xslx`

Comment: @Hunman, that has done the trick.  I used suggestion 1.  Thanks a million!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the last part of my code to read

`$writer->save(php_sapi_name() === 'cli' ? 'report_name.xlsx' : 'php://output');`

did the trick.  Thanks to @Hunman for the suggested solutions.